# How to exclude particular jar file from class path in windows command line?

Tags: java, regex, windows, cmd

I have hundred's jars files in particular folder, 
    1. a.jar
    2. b.jar
    3. c.jar
    4. d.jar ...etc
I need to run a java application with these jars in class path, except particular one in command prompt.
That is

> $ java -cp c:\jarfolder*(except c.jar) Mainclass

I cannot remove that jar alone from that folder, because it causes some other problem. So please help me with exact solution.

Comment: Specify each jar individually. If that is too much work to do often, write a .bat to set the classpath as a variable and call java. Note that the batch interpreter offers ways of listing files, but probably it won't be worth the effort to learn to use that.

Comment: @SJuan76 Thanks for your response. Yes, I have that as a work around solution, but I need to do it using regex.

Comment: You can a replace of `\bc\.jar\b` with `empty string`.

Comment: @vks This is also work around solution, but I need to do it in optimized way, I expect some regex which addresses my question

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple batch file which loops over all the files in the folder and excludes the files which you don't want using it you can create the classpath string and run the java command in the final step.

Comment: Yes, we can do in that way, but I have to do it using regex.

Comment: Not very sure but can you try using FINDSTR command and pipe the output to java command ? Sorry i work on mac so cant run it locally. :)