# Add all jar files to java classpath except of some ones

Tags: java, classpath

We know the class path entry `foo/*` as value of `classpath`, specifies all JAR files in the directory named `foo`. Now I have a long list of jar files in `foo` and want to add all of them to the `classpath` (by JDK tools' `-cp` option) except of "unwanted.jar".

In `Git` we can exclude "unwanted.jar" by adding this rule to `gitignore`:

```
foo/*
!foo/unwanted.jar
```

Is there a quick way to do this for `classpath` except of adding them manually by using `:` character or moving them to another directory?

Comment: Did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886045/how-to-exclude-particular-jar-file-from-class-path-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: @TuyenNguyen Thank you! Writing a script to do that, seems to be good way. But I want to wait for more replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux or OS X using this will do the job:

```
ls -1 $PWD/foo/*.jar | grep -v 'unwanted1.jar\|unwanted2.jar' | tr '\n' ':'
```

So you can use it together with `java` command:

```
java -cp `ls -1 $PWD/foo/*.jar | grep -v 'unwanted.jar\|unwanted2.jar' | tr '\n' ':'` ...
```